# How to copy specific subdirectories to a new directory?

Tags: bash, python, directory, cp

I am trying to copy specific subdirectories (and the files contained in them) to a new directory. Assuming I am in the first directory (`dir0/`), this contains a number of subdirectories named `000/`, `001/`, `002/`, ... and so on. Each of these subdirectories contains 1000 sub-subdirectories, with files inside them. One example could be: `dir0/000/aaa/file1.txt` or `dir0/001/bbb/file2.txt`.

I have a .txt file containing a list of the subdirectories to copy (I only have the name of the subdirectories, not the full path), so, for the example above, my txt file will contain this information:

```
aaa
bbb
```

Is there a way to copy all the subdirectories whose names are included in the txt file to a new directory using bash or python?

Thank you for your help. I am new to both bash and python.

Comment: What should happen if you have `dir0/000/aaa/` and also `dir0/018/aaa/`? Or can you be 100% sure that all the names in your text file will be unique?

Comment: the names in the text files are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that, as you said in the comments, the names in the text file are unique, that there will only be *one* subdirectory with that name in the entire directory tree, then you can simply do (in bash):

```
while read -r dirName; do
    cp -r dir0/*/"$dirName"/ /path/to/newTargetDir
done < listOfDirs.txt
```